# SSMS - Removing Underscores and Hyphens

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL Code:

```
drop table if exists #test;
go
--------
select
    'Student_is_behind_–_concerned_about_his_or_her_ability_to_catch_ nvarchar(255), ' as [test_col_1]
into
    #test;
go
----------------
select
    [test_col_1]
    ,replace([test_col_1],'_-_','_') as [col_1_adj]
from
    #test;
go
```

The output, despite the replace function, is:

```
Student_is_behind_–_concerned_about_his_or_her_ability_to_catch_ nvarchar(255),
```

I want to replace `_-_` with `_`.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit #1:**

For some reason, it works when I don't put the value in a column, but I have no idea why.

Comment: `_–_` <> `_-_` (the "hyphen" characters are different)

Comment: Post this as the answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'_-_'` you used in the Replace function not the same as in the `'Student_is_behind_–_concerned_about_his_or_her_ability_to_catch_ nvarchar(255), '`
if you change it it will work.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1982a6d2ffc368835018fca8ec30e985)